# Definition of convolution for $u \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n).$ We define a convolution of $u$ and $\varphi$ by
$$ (u* \varphi)(x) = \langle u, \varphi (x- \cdot)\rangle$$
and $u* \varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

How can I know that the above definition is good for $u \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Also in that case, the right hand side of the definition is well-defined. Do you know how $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ extends from $\mathcal{D}'\times C^\infty_c$ to $\mathcal{E}'\times C^\infty$?

Comment: How to do such an extension? @md2perpe

Comment: I know that calling this action a "convolution" is very traditional, but this often leads people to slip into thinking that it has the properties that a "more genuine" convolution would have... such as associativity. I know it's probably hopeless, but it might be better to refer to it as an (integral?) _action_ of the one thing on the other. This better avoids the iconic non-associativity $1*(\delta'*H)=1*\delta=1$, versus $(1*\delta')*H=0*H=0$, where $H$ is Heaviside's function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u\in\mathcal{D}'$ have compact support and $\varphi\in C^\infty$. Take $\rho\in C^\infty_c$ such that $\rho\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $\operatorname{supp} u.$ Then $\rho\varphi\in C^\infty_c$ so $\langle u, \rho\varphi \rangle$ is defined. Its value is also independent of choice of $\rho$ since different choices will only differ outside of the support of $u$. We can therefore extend $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ to $\mathcal{E}'\times C^\infty$ by setting
$$\langle u, \varphi \rangle := \langle u, \rho\varphi \rangle.$$

The extension of the convolution follows from this extension.